# Batch Class and grouped by

Tags: apex, soql

I'm trying to figure out how I can use a batch class to run a process I have.  I basically need to select all accounts that are set to expire based on a custom date field. I then need to group those records by two fields trackNumber and attachedGroup, I then create a new custom object for that group, then create a custom child object for each account that's in that group and assign them to the parent custom object.

My issue is, if I use a batch class,how do I know my data won't span batches?  Lets say my batch is 10, well what if account 10 and 11 are for the same trackNumber and AttachedGroup, they won't run through the process together.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you ultimately need individual custom objects for each account that is expiring, while the [critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) of the application is actually associating those child objects to the group objects.  So, you can split your work by first inserting all the child objects using your batch class, then having your batch's `finish` method start a `Queueable` job which goes through all of the child objects without parents and associates them to a parent, creating new objects if necessary.

Another option in the vein of the above is to create and associate the group objects in the trigger of the child objects - I believe the database will always run triggers for the same object in sequence, so your trigger just has to check whether the group object already exists and create it if it does not.